# My Ubuntu version is 22.04 is disconnecting from WIFI after some time

Tags: networking, 22.04, network-manager

I ran this Command `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`
and the thing I found in log is :

`Jan 31 12:09:26 jitender NetworkManager[586]: <info>  [1706683166.5640] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)`

Above this I have also switched the Powersaving mode to 2 and also the restarted the Network Manager Service

`sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`
It still persist and I have disabled IPV6

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

There is a bit of SKILL ISSUE I feel I have if you know pls help

Comment: Please run the `wireless-info` script: https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/1004020